# Booting up my Ruby social aggregator app

Tags: ruby

[image: Banner]

Some time ago I started with a small Ruby project. I call it `social_aggregator`.
This software aggregates information from different networks to one xml-stream, which you can reuse. For instance on your personal website to show some of your activity to your audience or as your personal news feed.

I've a built in `Webrick` server, while I also want to support any other rack based server. So I have this two entry/start points:

`config.ru`:

```
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(File.dirname(__FILE__))

require 'Aggregator'
require 'conf/router'

# Run aggregator
app = Thread.new{ Aggregator.new }
app.run

use ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionManagement
use ActiveRecord::QueryCache

run Router.map
```

And the `Aggregator.rb`:

```
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(File.dirname(__FILE__))

require 'conf/initializers/DatabaseInitializer'
require 'conf/initializers/ConsoleInitializer'
require 'app/plugins/PluginManager'
require 'app/utils/ArgumentParser'
require 'app/utils/Logging'
require 'app/utils/Setting'

# Main class
class Aggregator
    include Logging
    include Setting

    # The version constant
    AGGREGATOR_VERSION = '0.0.1' unless const_defined?(:AGGREGATOR_VERSION)

    # Stores the environment
    @@environment = :production

    # Stores the run state
    @@stop = false

    # Initialize the whole system
    def initialize(internal_server = false, arguments = [])
        options = ArgumentParser.parse(arguments)

        Logging::environment options.environment

        # Set up logger
        if options.quiet
            Logging::quiet = true
        end

        logger.info 'Starting up aggregator now'

        # Set environment to setting
        logger.info "Using #{options.environment} environment"
        @@environment = options.environment

        # Connect database with orm
        DatabaseInitializer.new(options.environment)

        unless options.environment == :test || options.console
            # Set up plugin manager
            @@plugin_manager = PluginManager.new 

            if internal_server
                require 'conf/initializers/ServerInitializer'

                # Spawn new server
                ServerInitializer.new
            end

            logger.info "Aggregator is up and running"

            Signal.trap("SIGINT") do
                Thread.current.exit
            end

            start
        end

        if options.console
            ConsoleInitializer.new(options.environment)
        end
    end

    # Returns the current environment
    def self.environment
        @@environment
    end

    # Returns the version number
    def self.version
        AGGREGATOR_VERSION
    end

    # Returns the plugin manager
    def self.plugin_manager
        @@plugin_manager
    end

    # Shutdown the system
    def self.shutdown
        @@stop = true
    end

    private

    # Starts the aggregation
    def start
        @@plugin_manager.run

        if @@stop
            logger.info "Stopping aggregation now, due request to stop."
            return
        end

        logger.debug "Aggregation done. Next aggregation in #{setting.aggregate_timer} seconds."

        sleep setting.aggregate_timer
        start
    end
end

# Initialize aggregator
if __FILE__ == $PROGRAM_NAME
    app = Aggregator.new(true, ARGV)
end
```

Is that a good way to realize a built in server as well as support for other app server?
If you're interested in the project, you can find it here: https://github.com/openscript/social_aggregator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the answer to [Implementing plugins in my Ruby social aggregator app](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/41830/implementing-plugins-in-my-ruby-social-aggregator-app) to see some general observations on your code style.

The most important thing I have to point out on this code is that your run loop is not a loop, but a recursion. This is especially bad, since it will eventually kill your whole application on a `StackOverflow` exception (pun?)

You should always use iteration over recursion when the loop is infinite:

```
def start
  until @@stop
    @@plugin_manager.run

    logger.debug "Aggregation done. Next aggregation in #{setting.aggregate_timer} seconds."

    sleep setting.aggregate_timer
  end
end
```

Also, you seem to mix instance scope and class scope. You allow for multiple `Aggregator`s, but there is only a single `shutdown`. Either design your class for multiple uses, in which case state and methods should be of the instance, or that it is a `Singleton`, for which there are [patterns in ruby](http://dalibornasevic.com/posts/9-ruby-singleton-pattern-again).

You seem to have a lot of comments in your code. Ruby encourages less comments, and more expressive method names. There is no point in a comment, if it does not add anything to the code itself. This code:

```
# Initialize aggregator
app = Aggregator.new(true, ARGV)
```

has no advantage to simply writing

```
app = Aggregator.new(true, ARGV)
```

Using static members (`@@stop`) is also not advisable. If you are writing inside the `self` scope (inside `def self.shutdown`) simple members (`@stop`) are actually in the class scope, being effectively static. To access them from outside this scope, add a getter:

```
def self.stop
  @stop
end
```

Which will be accessible by calling `Aggregator.stop`.

Refactored `Aggregator`:

```
class Aggregator
  include Logging
  include Setting

  AGGREGATOR_VERSION = '0.0.1'

  def self.version
    AGGREGATOR_VERSION
  end

  attr_reader :environment, :plugin_manager, :stop

  def initialize(internal_server = false, arguments = [])
    options = ArgumentParser.parse(arguments)

    Logging::environment options.environment
    Logging::quiet = true if options.quiet

    logger.info 'Starting up aggregator now'

    logger.info "Using #{options.environment} environment"
    @environment = options.environment

    DatabaseInitializer.new(options.environment)

    return if options.environment == :test

    if options.console
      ConsoleInitializer.new(options.environment)
    else
      @plugin_manager = PluginManager.new 

      ServerInitializer.new if internal_server

      logger.info "Aggregator is up and running"

      Signal.trap("SIGINT") do
        Thread.current.exit
      end

      start
    end
  end

  def shutdown
    @stop = true
  end

  private

  def start
    until stop
      @plugin_manager.run

      logger.debug "Aggregation done. Next aggregation in #{setting.aggregate_timer} seconds."
      sleep setting.aggregate_timer
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for this great review. I've no clue, why I can't replace my static members with getters and setters. When I access them via a static getter method they are always `nil`.
https://github.com/openscript/social_aggregator/blob/master/aggregator.rb

Comment: What I still wonder, if it's a good idea to have this built in Webrick server beside my `config.ru`. What do you think about it?

Comment: @Sam - read my answer carefully about using static members - you should not use the `@@` directive anywhere - to assign to the class variables call the setter (`Aggregator.stop='my_version'`), and it should work. Getters and setters in the class scope (`def self.stop=`) will set `@stop` to the class, not the instance, and vice versa.

Comment: I would _not_ recommend using `Webrick` for anything but the development phase. Choose your webserver according to your application's sizing requirements. The simplest webserver I would advise you to look at is `thin`. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10859671/webrick-as-production-server-vs-thin-or-unicorn